# Proof on booleans, false = true

Tags: coq

I currently am at chapter 5 of "Software foundations" but felt the need to get back to chapter one to clarify a couple of things. In particular there is an exercise I did not quite digested, in which we are asked to use destruct twice to prove a result on booleans. Here it is with names and other details changed.

```
Inductive bool: Type :=
|true: bool
|false: bool.

Definition fb (b1:bool) (b2:bool) : bool :=
match b1, b2 with
| false, false => false
| _, _ => true
end.

Theorem th: forall a b: bool,
  fb a b = false -> b = false.
Proof.
intros [] [] H.
- rewrite <- H. reflexivity.
- reflexivity.
- rewrite <- H. reflexivity.
- reflexivity.
Qed.
```

When at the first tick, context and goal are both nonsense:

```
H : fb true true = false
______________________________________(1/1)
true = false
```

Second tick the hypothesis is false. Third tick is same kind of nonsense as first one. Only fourth tick is reasonable with:

```
H : fb false false = false
______________________________________(1/1)
false = false
```

I understand that by the rewrite rules, all these things do work. However I have the impression we are quitting the narrow path of truth for the wilderness of falsity. More precisely, and AFAIK, a false hypothesis can be made to prove ANY statement, true or false. Here we use it to prove that false = true, OK why not, but still that makes me feel somewhat uncomfortable. I would not have expected a proof assistant to allow this.

**Elaborating a bit**

In a typical proof by contradiction, I would pick an hypothesis at random, and derive the goal till I find either a tautology or a contradiction. I would then conclude whether my hypothesis was true or false.

What happens here, in cases 1 (same for case 3), Coq starts from an hypothesis that is false:

```
H : fb true true = false
```

applies it to a goal that is a contradiction:

```
true = false
```

and combines them to find a tautology.

That is not a way of reasoning I am aware of. That recalls student 'jokes' where starting with 0=1 any absurd result on natural numbers can be proven.

**Followup**

So this morning during my commute I was thinking about what I had just written above. I now believe that cases 1 and 3 are proper proofs by contradiction. Indeed H is false and we use it to prove a goal that is a false. Hypotheses (values of a and b) have to be rejected. What may have confused me is that using rewrite we are doing part of the way "backward", starting from the goal.

I am a bit undecided for case 2, which reads:

```
H : fb true false = false
______________________________________(1/1)
false = false
```

which is basically `false -> true`, a tautology under the "principle of explosion". I would not think that could be used so directly in a proof.

Oh well, not sure I completely understood what's under the hood, but trust in Coq is untouched. Gotta go on and return to chapter 5. Thanks all for your comments.

Comment: Case distinctions may have impossible cases, and they can be dispatched/ruled out by deriving falsehood. This is common and valid logical reasoning.

Comment: I cannot quite tell what you find confusing about this example; would you care to elaborate? Is it that Coq is producing sub-goals that have contradictory hypotheses in them?

Comment: Maybe the confusion happened in the "in a typical proof by contradiction" Indeed, you are not doing a proof by contradicition here but you are using the "explosion principle". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion also known as "Ex Falso, Quodlibet" , "From falsity anything is true", which seems to be a pretty fashionable principle these days.

Comment: The principle of explosion (thanks for the reference) may have a use in "alternative mathematics", but I do not see any in a classical proof.

Comment: @Balzola indeed it has many uses once you are in a formal proof system, mainly to rule out impossible cases.

Comment: Anyways for a better understanding of the principle, assume we are in first-order Peano Arithmetic. Now, imagine you arrive to have as an hypotheses `0=1` Indeed, it is easy to see that from that, you can prove that any two numbers are equal, and indeed you can prove any statement! Is that magic? No, it is not. In fact, you could think of it as "eliminating impossible cases". Imagine you are trying to prove something for positive numbers, thus you have `x > 0`, then, when you apply induction, you will get `0>0` which is not possible, so in a sense, you are done.

Comment: @ejgallego I have had at most one hour of course in my scholarship about the rules of inference, and that was mainly to introduce `P->Q <-> -Q -> -P`. That is also one of my goal in studying Coq, to get familiar wih this.

Comment: That's a different rule. The rule you are using here is `∀ φ, ⊥ → φ`, where the `∀` is a meta-quantifier if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, thanks for providing a self-contained code.

I understand your uneasiness proving a goal using [`rewrite`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.rewrite) when you know that what you really ought to do is to derive a contradiction from the hypotheses. That does not make the reasoning incorrect though. It is true that under such assumptions you can prove this goal.

However I also think that this does not make the proof script really readable. In your example, you are considering all possible cases and it happens that three out of these four are impossible. When we read your proof we cannot see that. To make it clear that you are in an impossible case, there are a few tactic which are useful to say "look, I am now going to prove a contradiction to rule out this case".

One of them is [`exfalso`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.exfalso). It will replace the current goal by `False` (since anything can be derived from `False`, as mentioned by @ejgallego in a comment).

A second one is [`absurd`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.absurd) to say "I am now going to prove some statement and its negation" (this is basically equivalent to proving False).

A third one which is enough in your case is [`discriminate`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.discriminate). It tries to find in the hypotheses a contradictory equality, such as `true = false`.

```
Theorem th: forall a b: bool,
  fb a b = false -> b = false.
Proof.
  intros [] [] H.
  - discriminate.
  - discriminate.
  - discriminate.
  - reflexivity.
Qed.
```

---

Now, just so you know, [`discriminate`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.discriminate) and [`reflexivity`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.reflexivity) are both tried by the [`easy`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.easy) tactic. Thus the following proof will work as well (but it does not show what is going on and thus falls out of the scope of this question):

```
Theorem th: forall a b: bool,
  fb a b = false -> b = false.
Proof.
  intros [] [] H; easy.
Qed.
```

and this is syntactic sugar for the same proof:

```
Theorem th: forall a b: bool,
  fb a b = false -> b = false.
Proof.
  now intros [] [] H.
Qed.
```

Comment: Accepting answer because of second paragraph ("I understand ..."). Looked at reference manual for `discriminate` and `exfalso` but that's not helping ... it is still jargon for me.

Comment: Don't worry about the manual. It's rarely clear unless you're quite experimented. I'll try to edit my answer to make it clearer.